# Alamofire encode [[String: Any]]

Tags: ios, json, alamofire

Alamofire's definition of Parameter:

```
/// A dictionary of parameters to apply to a URLRequest.
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
```

Parameter is used to encode the URL request.

The API I'm working with that has a PUT endpoint that expects the post body to be formatted as

```
[[String: Any]]
```

Would anyone have any way to provide the correct encoding?  Thanks.

edit:  If this is something that is not within the normal JSON coding standards, please provide a link that I could use to prove my case to the people in charge of my API spec.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire doesn't have built in support for such parameters, but you can encode them into the `URLRequest` yourself before using Alamofire to issue it, or write an extension to `SessionManager` that can take parameters of that form and use your own parameter encoder to create the `URLRequest`.

Comment: While this answer did not give me exactly what I needed, it certainly was a good suggestion which helped lead me to a solution that did work.